# Ordenar Taxonomías (Interno en Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

por mucho buscar no encuentro como ordenar las Taxonomías (No sus términos).
Con este código php muestro la lista de las Taxonomias que tengo:

```
 $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(); 
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy . '</p>';
}
```

1. Resultando en:

   - category
   - post_tag
   - pueblo
   - ciudad
   - **categoriaimportante** (taxonomia que quiero que sea la principal, que saliera la primera en el array) Como se ve, aparece la última y esto quiere decir que WP prioriza las anteriores.. No valdría "trucar" ese foreach, sino que de forma predeterminada por el core de WP detecte como principal esta taxonomia.

Hay algún campo que las ordene en la base de datos?  Algún codigo para el functions? Plugins los probé todos.

Saludos

Comment: `Algún codigo para el functions? Plugins los probé todos.` = **[edit] tu pregunta** con lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Pero podrías usar un plugin: https://es-mx.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Ese plugin solo ordena los términos, y no lo que yo necesito: Ordenar las taxonomías entre sí..

Comment: `esto quiere decir que WP prioriza las anteriores`, no necesariamente... ¿tienes algo que demuestre eso?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Establecer una Taxonomia como principal en Wordpress?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66399/establecer-una-taxonomia-como-principal-en-wordpress)

Comment: Un array de las taxonomías es lo que lo demuestra. Al fin al utilicé otro plugin que creaba las taxonomías "por detrás" de la principal.

Answer (score 0):

Con este código puedes mostrar las taxonomias no incorporadas primero:

```
    <?php 
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false

); 
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
if ( $taxonomies ) {
  foreach ( $taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy . '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

Y después podrías mostrar las taxonomias incorporadas modificando el atributo builtin por true.

```
    <?php 
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => true

); 
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
if ( $taxonomies ) {
  foreach ( $taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy . '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```